# Multiple y-axes chart with Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

In Plotly for Python, we have this beautiful multiple y-axis example:
[image]
here is the [link](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/) for the code.

I tried to do the same with Plotly in R using this code:

```
  library(plotly)

x <- 1:4
y1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
y2 <- c(4,3,2,1)
y3 <- c(1,4,1,4)
y4 <- c(4,1,4,1)

test <- data.frame(x, y1, y2, y3, y4)

plot_ly(data = test, x = ~x, y = ~y1
        ,type = "scatter", mode = "lines", width = 800, color = I("red")
        ,name = "name01") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y2, yaxis = "y2", color = I("blue"), name = "name02") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y3, yaxis = "y3", color = I("purple"), name = "name03") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y4, yaxis = "y4", color = I("green"), name = "name04") %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(
      showline = FALSE, side = "left"
      ,title = "Label 1"
      ,color = "red"
    )
    ,yaxis2 = list(
      showline = FALSE
      ,overlaying = "y"
      ,title = "Label 2", anchor = "free"
      ,color = "blue"
    )
    ,yaxis3 = list(
      showline = FALSE, side = "right", overlaying = "y"
      ,title = "Label 3"
      ,color = "purple"
    )
    ,yaxis4 = list(
      showline = FALSE, side = "right", overlaying = "y", position = 1
      ,title = "Label 4", anchor = "free"
      ,color = "green"
    )
    ,xaxis = list(
      showline = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, dtick = 1, title = ""
    )
    ,showlegend = FALSE
    ,margin = list(
      pad = 30, b = 90, l = 150, r = 90
    )
    ,legend = list(orientation = "h")
  )
```

But I get these overlapping labels:

[image]

How can I fix it to get a non overlapping chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tuning the padding (`pad`) value for `margin` argument of `layout()`.

Best I found for your other parameters is with `pad = 49`

[image]

Comment: Based on this discussion https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-y-axes-name-on-top-of-each-other/10663/3 you can also limit the range for the x-axis using `xaxis = list(domain=c(0,.9))` to make more room for the additional y-axes. You can then place the y-axes using `position`. In this case `position` would be between 0.9 and 1.

Comment: the comment by @simoet above works great!!! especially if legend and secondary axis is overlapping