# Multiple y-axes using plotly with data of different length

Tags: r, plot, plotly, yaxis

Using plotly I often had trouble with multiple line plot and data of different length. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953875/plotting-graphs-lines-based-on-column-values-from-the-same-datafram-using-plotly) solution:

```
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Merc", "Merc", "Merc", "Toyota", "Toyota"),
  date = c('10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/2/12', '10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/3/12'),
  Value = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2)
)

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%m/%d/%y")

df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~date, y=~Value, type='scatter', color=~id, mode="lines+markers") %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="Date"),yaxis=list(title="Cars Sold"))
```

Now I face the next problem. How can I add multiple y-axes to this example? Is it furthermore possible to have more than 2 y-axes using R and order them left and right like in [this](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/) Python example at the very bottom of the page? E.g. Honda and Merc left, Toyota right. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249315/multiple-y-axes-chart-with-plotly-in-r), but the data has the same length, so this is not working for me.

I want to prevent the scaling of data with different order of magnitude like in this data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Merc", "Merc", "Merc", "Toyota", "Toyota"),
  date = c('10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/2/12', '10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/3/12'),
  Value = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Merc", "Merc", "Merc", "Toyota", "Toyota"),
  yaxis = c("y", "y", "y", "y2", "y2", "y2", "y3", "y3"),
  date = c('10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/2/12', '10/30/12', '10/31/12', '11/1/12', '11/3/12'),
  Value = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2)
)

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%m/%d/%y")

y2 <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "left",
  title = "Merc",
  position=0.1,
  showgrid = FALSE
)

y3 <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "green"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = "Toyota",
  showgrid = FALSE
)

df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~date, y=~Value, type='scatter', color=~id, mode="lines+markers", yaxis=~yaxis) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="Date", domain = list(0.15, 0.95)), yaxis=list(title="Honda"), yaxis2=y2, yaxis3=y3)
```

[image: Result]

For further information please see [this](https://plot.ly/r/multiple-axes/).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to show only the grid from the first dataset (-> Honda) to prevent overlaying of the grids?

Comment: Sure, I adapted the code accordingly. You should try using `schema()` which let's you navigate through plotly's attributes.